# Sound stutters through bluetooth

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth speaker that I've been using without any problem for the last 2 years.

After the last upgrade to 14.04 I cannot use it anymore because after a few minutes the sound starts stuttering, it has a lot of delay and sometimes it sounds like it accelerates to get the audio back in sync.

I'm having the same problem with any sound source (vlc, youtube, rhythmbox, spotify) and using the speaker with my phone does not give me any problem.

Also, I've checked the cpu usage when this happens and it's not high.

Has anybody else experienced this problem?

Comment: This bug report may be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1594591

Answer (score 1):

Try with installing the related packages with `bluez`:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev  libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3 python-gobject python-dbus
```

Comment: Do I have to configure something else? After installing everything and rebooting is still stuttering.